# read the following link

Tags: java, hyperlink

i want to go to next page of the following link

```
<a href="javascript: __doPostBack('ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$g_781eb52f_faa9_4d59_9cae_2baec06ac484','dvt_firstrow={51};dvt_startposition={Paged=TRUE&amp;p_Created_x0020_Date=6%2f9%2f2009%208%3a33%3a19%20AM&amp;p_ID=216}');">
<img src="/_layouts/images/next.gif" border="0" alt="Next"></a></td></tr></table></div></td>
```

how can i go next in java program

Comment: <a href="javascript: __doPostBack('ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$g_781eb52f_faa9_4d59_9cae_2baec06ac484','dvt_firstrow={51};dvt_startposition={Paged=TRUE&amp;p_Created_x0020_Date=6%2f9%2f2009%208%3a33%3a19%20AM&amp;p_ID=216}');"><img src="/_layouts/images/next.gif" border="0" alt="Next"></a></td></tr></table></div></td>

Comment: Are you sure you’re using Java?

Comment: yas i am reading the public web page using java but i can not go to the second page that the html code is the link i post

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible crawl ASP.NET pages?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133020/is-it-possible-crawl-asp-net-pages)

Comment: This link is generated by ASP.Net and requires javascript on the client to work.  You can only get to the next page if javascript works, do you have it enabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried [HttpUnit](http://httpunit.sourceforge.net/)? It has API for some basic JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

This is just an observation... but from the code you have given, the link is a postback, not an actual "link" in the traditional sense. You will need to click on the link, in the page, in context, for it to do anything meaningful.

Using the code out of context will not (should not) work. The codebehind for that page will determine exactly what will happen when the postback is sent.

In all likeliness, your session has expired and the postback will do nothing...

Do you own/control the page's code? If you do, can you post the ASP and codebehind?

Comment: no i do not own it i am loding the page as the following new InputStreamReader(
    new URL(url).openStream()));

Answer (score 0):

Paged=TRUE&p_Created_x0020_Date=6%2f9%2f2009%208%3a33%3a19%20AM&p_ID=216

I guess Paged,p_Created_Date,p_ID are parameters you need to pass, to go to next page.