# java read a web page using url

Tags: java, url

how to read next page of the same URL

the  URL of the page contain many pages i read the first page using

```
URL(url).openStream()
```

but it just reading the first page

for example this site i read the first page how can i read the second culture.gov.uk/news/news_stories/6832.aspx

Comment: Dont ask duplicates of your own questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4438519/read-the-following-link, edit the first one and try to make it sensible

Comment: There is no such thing as the next page of an URL. An URL corresponds to one page. It could contain links to other pages, but that has nothing to do with the original URL. And there is no natural ordering, so it's impossible to tell which page is "next".

Comment: thanks for example this site i read the first page how can i read the second                                                                 http://www.culture.gov.uk/news/news_stories/6832.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next page will have some link.

You can parse HTML and collect all the links and then you can filter out which is the next link for this page and then read it same way.

[Here is the example that will list all the links from given page. - using JSOUP](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/example-list-links)

Note: It is certainly ill-legal to do this for some sites.

Answer (score 0):

You will need the URL scheme for paging. For example it can be `url + "?page=" + page`. It depends on the site. Note that [scraping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping) is not always [legal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping#Legal_issues).