# Crawler for Deep-Web calling ASP.NET page

Tags: asp.net, web-crawler, deep-web

**Introduction**

I'm developing a web-crawler and I need get the return of **`ASP.NET`** forms.
I know about the difficult to try that, but my crawler can get the return of PHP forms or languages like that. I'm using **`HtmlAgilityPack`** and call with POST parameters. That works fine.

**Problem**

My problem starts when I need crawler ASP.NET Forms, with a lot of hiddens fields and other the information (like **`__VIEWSTATE or __EVENTARGUMENT`**) for ASP.NET Kernel.

**Question**

How Can I put for my crawler send a POST call and receive the correct return with the data base filters? Somebody have information about that? Somebody tried something like that?

Thank's everybody.
I'm waiting for a good response.

Comment: why are you crawling pages with POST?

Comment: Question about it here too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133020/is-it-possible-crawl-asp-net-pages

Comment: I'm crawling pages by POST, because I need catch some data behind a search form. I need send parameters to filter the data.

Comment: i have same issue. i am passing __VIEWSTATE, __EVENTARGUMENT and other params which page post to server at usually BUT it doesnt worl standart alone.